# Condition for existence of solutions of a system of first order PDE

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Consider (locally) the following system of linear first order PDEs:
$$
\forall\,1\leq j<k\leq n,\quad \frac{\partial F_k}{\partial x_j}-\frac{\partial F_j}{\partial x_k} = \nu_{jk}(x),
$$
for the unknown functions $F_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, and source terms $\nu_{jk}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

**Question**: Give conditions for the existence of smooth solutions $(F_1,\ldots,F_n)$.

An idea is to apply Frobenius theorem, but for that one should split the system in separate equations for each unknown. I do not succeed in finding such splitting.

**Solution**: Based on comment of Ted and Ivo, the necessary and sufficient condition is simply $d\nu=0$ where $\nu=\sum_{k<j}\nu_{k,j}dx_k\wedge dx_j$ is a differential 2-form.

Comment: Of course, your source terms must satisfy the integrability condition that the $2$-form  $\nu = \sum_{j<k} \nu_{jk}dx_j\wedge dx_k$ be *closed*. Then it's just the Poincaré lemma. Where are you getting Frobenius?

Comment: To elaborate on Ted's comment: in terms of differential forms, your system is ${\rm d}F = \nu$, where $F = \sum_i F_i\,{\rm d}x_i$. That's how he came up with the Poincaré lemma.

Comment: Ty for your answers, that is also the solution that I came up in my sleep.

Comment: @TedShifrin, but can't you solve this using Frobenius?

Comment: @Deane I don’t see a collection of $1$-forms, only the $2$-form $\nu$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @TedShifrin, prolongation!

Comment: @Deane Yes, but that’s going way past the usual Frobenius and into EDS land.

Comment: @TedShifrin, no. Since the Poincaré lemma is solved using only repeated integration, the differential system has to reduce to an application of the Frobenius theorem. I'll post the details.

Comment: @Deane Yes, do, please, but the sophistication of prolongation far exceeds standard first-year graduate manifolds! Unless Robert or you’re teaching it with lots of extra time! :)

Comment: @TedShifrin, you're right, and I was wrong. I forgot that this system of PDEs is quite degenerate, In terms of EDS, it means there are nontrivial Cauchy characteristics. So it probably can be reduced to Frobenius but it would require more work than it's worth. I'm now curious about what solution the OP came up with in their sleep.

Comment: Ty for the discussion. :) The solution I found is also the one with differential form. I realised that my system of pde is $d F=\nu$ as thus the integrability condition is $d\nu=0$.

Comment: Btw, do you have idea for an interpretation of the following system of pdes (for the unknown $\beta_j^i$, for $1\leq i,j\leq n$) in terms of differential forms? 
$\sum_{l=1}^{n}\left(\frac{\partial \beta_j^i}{\partial y_l}\beta_k^l-\frac{\partial \beta_k^i}{\partial y_l}\beta_j^l\right)=0$, for all $1\leq i,j,k\leq n$.